# Is it possible to start a Selenium test case in Firefox with a single click?

Tags: firefox, selenium, firefox-addon, selenium-ide

Is it possible to run a Selenium test case in Firefox with a single click using a button in the add-on bar? Or would I have to open the Selenium UI first, load the test case and run it?

After all the idea of Selenium is to automate browser navigation. Being able to put a test case on a single-click button would be a huge improvement in my opinion.

If this is not possible, is there a way to open the Selenium UI with the TestSuite loaded that has been loaded on last close? Selenium is not doing this by default, I'm really wondering why.

Answer (score 0):

The add on you are looking for is Selnium IDE Favroites.

You can install it from [here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/favorites-selenium-ide/).

** EDIT **
Actual steps to set it up

- Click on the favorite toolbar button to add the current test suite to favorites.
- Click on the drop down arrow on the favorite toolbar button to see the list of favorite test suites.
- Click on one of the test suites to open them.
- Ctrl + click on one of the test suites to open and execute them.
- You can also use the Favorite menu.**

Comment: I know about this one. But I have to open the Selenium UI first to be able to use it. Can I also put it directly in Firefox into the add-on bar?

Comment: yup thats what the description says. :)

Comment: I double-checked again. It only appears in the Selenium Ui and cannot be put to the add-on bar. If I'm wrong, please let me know how to.

Answer (score 0):

You will have greater flexibility in automation if you move to Selenium WebDriver from Selenium IDE. You can automate the test suites with a single click.